# PHP Explode File Search

Tags: php, html, file, loops

Evening all,

I'm trying to achieve the following:

> I have a variable: $product - which is in the format xxxx-xx (length of characters on each side of - can differ)
>
> I have a folder location: $vault_folder - this is a UNC path to a remote server
>
> Inside $vault_folder are PDF files that are in the format of xxxx-xx-xx.pdf (again length of characters on each side of - can differ)
>
> I need to search $vault_folder first two parts e.g. (xxxx-xx)-xx.pdf for $product (xxxx-xx)
>
> If there is a match then take the whole file name e.g. xxxx-xx-xx.pdf and store as $filename (there will only ever be 1 result in the folder)

My Original Idea was to return all filenames into a single dimensional array then string split these so it is a multi dimensional array e.g. (xxxx)-(xx)-(xx)

then string split $product

then search for $product in the multi dimensional and if it finds then return that row in the multi dimensional array into separate variables e.g. $1=(xxxx) $2(xx) $3(xx)

I am completely running round in circles with this and cant figure out the best way to achieve what I want.

New to PHP so any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Bepster

Comment: '/(\d+)-(\d+)(\d+)/' http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php and RecursiveRegexIterator

Comment: Too epistolar. It should be just a question.

Answer (score 0):

If the product and the filenames are formatted in exactly the same way, you could probably retrieve a list of all the filenames into an array, and then `preg_grep` for `/xxxx-xxx-(\d+)/`, where you replace the x's with your exact $product.